# Crontab task to execute every weekday from 22:00 to 0500

Tags: linux

I have this listed in cron.

***/10 22-5 * * 1-5 /home/xfinity/Dropbox/take-pic.sh**

The script is ok. All permission. What could be wrong with it?

Answer (score 3):

Split the hour range to:

```
*/10 22-23,0-5 * * 1-5 /home/xfinity/Dropbox/take-pic.sh
```

Just a hint: it will execute until 5:50 not just till 5:00.

Comment: this also run on monday early moring (intended ?) and not on saturday morning.